# How to send a message to or post on wall of a facebook friend using spring social facebook api

Tags: facebook, spring-social-facebook

I have an application which imports facebook friends as contacts using spring social facebook. I want to invite this facebook friends to join the app. Is there a way to send a private message to selected facebook friends or to post on selected facebook friends' wall using spring social api?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can´t post on the wall of a friend (because that would always be spam), and you can´t send a message with the API.

You may want to read this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#invite_to_app

The proper way is to use the Send/Message Dialog, or the Request Dialog if your App is a game.

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't possible. In order for you to send messages of any kind to a Facebook user, you need that user's permission to do so.

If someone logs into your site with Facebook Connect, they are explicitly agreeing to share their Facebook data with your site, and you will then be able to send that person a message through the normal channels. You would also be able to fetch their friend list. However, you can not send messages to the friends.